# Post cookie data and return the value

Tags: python, security, cookies

I'm making a program that tries brute forcing a cookie value with python. 
I'm working on an environment that is meant for IT-security students, it's like a CTF-as-a-service. 
The mission i'm working on is a badly programmed login site that has a weak way of creating a cookie session. 
The cookie consist of three values, an integer returned from the server side, the username, and a hash. I've already managed to acquire the username and hash, but i need to brute force the **int value**.

I have never done anything with cookies or tried to brute force them. 
I was thinking i can manually observer the program running and returning the header of the site, until the content-length changes.

This is the code i have at the moment.

```
from requests import session
import Cookie
def createCook(salt):
  #known atrributes for the cookie
  salt = int('to_be_brute_forced')
  user = str('user')
  hash = str('hash_value')
  # create the cookies
  c = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
  #assing cookie name(session) and values (s,u,h)
  c['session'] = salt + user + hash
  c['session']['domain'] = '127.0.0.1:7777'
  c['session']['path'] = "/"
  c['session']['expires'] = 1*1*3*60*60
  print c 

def Main():
 print "Feed me Seymour: "
 salt = 0
 while (salt < 1000):
     print 'this is the current cookie: ', createCook(salt)
     cc = createCook(salt)
     salt = salt + 1
     try:
        with session() as s:
            s.post('http://127.0.0.1:7777/index.php', data=cc)
            request = s.get('http://127.0.0.1:7777/index.php')
            print request.headers
            print request.text
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
 Main()
```

So my questions are: 
 1. Do i need to save the cookie before posting?
 2. How do i always add +1 to the salt and recreate the cookie?
 3. how do i post it to the site and know that the correct one is found?

Comment: In a *normal* login process, you would usually want to save the cookie, which is what `requests.session` helps you with. You tell the server your password, the server in response creates a (hopefully secure) cookie for your and asks your client to set it, and your client sends that cookie with every subsequent request to the server.

Comment: When trying to brute force the hash however, you'll want to send a different cookie every time. So you might not even want to use `requests.session`, but instead create your own cookies (you already have the code in place for that), and create and send a new one with every request. See [the `request` docs on cookies](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies) on how to do manual cookie handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While posting the request you have to use cookies as the argument instead of data

```
s.post(url, cookies=<cookiejar>)
```